# Is Settings::set() a valid function?

Tags: 8, configuration

Can I set value like `Settings::set('some-variable','hello')`?

As if we can get value using `Settings::get('some-variable')` then why the '`set`' method is not working?

Comment: The reason you can't set settings is that settings is a read-only wrapper of things defined in settings.php. You can't rewrite that from code, you actually need to do it by changing $settings.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not call Settings::set. You should get an

```
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::set() in ...
```

Maybe there's something wrong with your error reporting or you imported any other Settings class (check your namespace). Check your php.ini for this. The Settings Class is for read-only access to the settings in settings.php.

If you need to set some system settings do it like this:

```
// themes
\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.theme')
->set('admin', 'bartik')
->save();
```